# How can I write this code to be more efficient

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, code-cleanup

I am learning Vue.js and I am setting up a website where I am using LocalStorage to store data.

I wrote some code, which is a little clunky and very repetitive:

```
<script>
const app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    explosive_pullups_1: '',
    explosive_pullups_2: '',
    explosive_pullups_3: '',
    tuck_front_raises_1: '',
    tuck_front_raises_2: '',
    tuck_front_raises_3: '',
  },
  mounted() {
    if (localStorage.explosive_pullups_1) {
      this.explosive_pullups_1 = localStorage.explosive_pullups_1;
    }
    if (localStorage.explosive_pullups_2) {
      this.explosive_pullups_2 = localStorage.explosive_pullups_2;
    }
    if (localStorage.explosive_pullups_3) {
      this.explosive_pullups_3 = localStorage.explosive_pullups_3;
    }
    if (localStorage.tuck_front_raises_1) {
      this.tuck_front_raises_1 = localStorage.tuck_front_raises_1;
    }
    if (localStorage.tuck_front_raises_2) {
      this.tuck_front_raises_2 = localStorage.tuck_front_raises_2;
    }
    if (localStorage.tuck_front_raises_3) {
      this.tuck_front_raises_3 = localStorage.tuck_front_raises_3;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    explosive_pullups_1(pullups1) {
      localStorage.explosive_pullups_1 = pullups1;
    },
    explosive_pullups_2(pullups2) {
      localStorage.explosive_pullups_2 = pullups2;
    },
    explosive_pullups_3(pullups3) {
      localStorage.explosive_pullups_3 = pullups3;
    },
    tuck_front_raises_1(tuck_front_raises1) {
      localStorage.tuck_front_raises_1 = tuck_front_raises1;
    },
    tuck_front_raises_2(tuck_front_raises2) {
      localStorage.tuck_front_raises_2 = tuck_front_raises2;
    },
    tuck_front_raises_3(tuck_front_raises3) {
      localStorage.tuck_front_raises_3 = tuck_front_raises3;
    },
  }
})
</script>
```

I would like to know a way to write this code to be less repetitive.

Comment: Have you looked at vuex. I highly recommend it for storing global variables within vue. It’s easy to setup and use. I would then consider using computed props instead of the data. Computed props will react to changes but are a little more tricky to set

Answer (score 1):

You can put the exercise data into its own object, and save that to `localStorage` instead. E.g.:

```js
<script>
const app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data: {
    exercises: {},
  },
  mounted() {
    this.exercises = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("exercises"));
  },
  watch: {
    exercises(newExerciseValues) {
      localStorage.setItem("exercises", JSON.stringify(newExerciseValues));
    },
  }
})
</script>
```

If you really need to store and retrieve the individual exercises explicitly, I would recommend keeping the data in one `exercises` object, and simply use a `for` loop to check/set everything. Something like this:

```js
[...]
watch: {
  exercises(newExercises) {
    const exercisesToCheck = [
      'explosive_pullups_1',
      'explosive_pullups_2',
      'explosive_pullups_3',
      'tuck_front_raises_1',
      'tuck_front_raises_2',
      'tuck_front_raises_3',
    ];

    for (const exercise of exercisesToCheck) {
      localStorage.setItem(exercise, this.exercises[exercise]);
    }
  },
},
[...]
```

On a side note, be very careful when working with objects in Vue. If you need to add a new exercise to the `exercises` object, avoid using `this.exercises['new_exercise'] = newExercise`. Instead, use `Vue.set(this.exercises, 'new_exercise', newExercise)`. Check out the [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) for an explanation.

Comment: You could you and index/key to generate the strings and loop through by a particular amount of numbers too. That way you don’t need to ever create an array.